# Scraping specific part of HTML website ID using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the id of the below html (1217428), without scraping the rest of the id tag, but I have no clue how to isolate only the desired portion.

```
<td class="pb-15 text-center">
<a href="#" id="1217428_1_10/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
    8:15 AM ✔ 
</a>
</td>
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
lesson_id = [] # I wish to fit the lesson id in this list
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
slots = soup.find(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"})
tag = slots.find("a")
ID = tag.attrs["id"]
print (ID)
```

But this only allows me to receive this as an output:

```
1217428_1_10/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Is there any way I could edit my code such that the output would be:

```
1217428
```

I have also tried using regex with this:

```
lesson_id = []
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
slots = soup.find(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"})
tag = slots.find("a")
ID = tag.attrs["id"]
lesson_id.append(ID(re.findall("\d{7}")))
```

But I receive this error:

```
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

Comment: For your `TypeError`: [`re.findall((pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) requires at least two arguments. For the rest, I can not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply split the sting as follows :

```
id_list = ID.split('_',1)
#will give you ['1217428', '1_10/6/2020 12:00:00 AM']
id = id_list[0] # which is '1217428'
```

You can use Regular Expression as well :

```
match = re.search(r'\d{1,}',ID)
id = match.group() # '1217428'
```

Comment: @maz you are welcome , accept the answer to close the question

Answer (score 1):

I think this you can solve your problem by splitting the id with "_" and using the first part. (this is what I understand from your above example):

```
lesson_id = [] # I wish to fit the lesson id in this list
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
slots = soup.find(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"})
tag = slots.find("a")
ID = tag.attrs["id"]
if ID:
    ID = ID.split("_")[0]
print (ID)
```

Comment: Welcome, do mark it as the answer so that this question is closed!

Comment: hi Dear Saurav - many thanks for this bright solution. Very interesting!